# Finding the current version of rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there a way of finding out what the current version of rails 2.3 is?  Right now the Ruby on Rails page has a link to a blog post about 2.3.11, but I imagine that after a few more blog posts that will no longer be there.  I tried to find a way with the "gem" command, but didn't see it.  If I run "gem update rails" I don't get any options-- it just updates me to rails 3.0.4, which I am not ready for yet.  I can do "gem install -v 2.3.11 rails" but that presumes that I know what the current version is.  Also, on the rails web site, there is a link to page on rubyforge where you can download the gem files but the latest one there is 2.3.4, so that is no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can run this command `gem list --remote -a | egrep "^rails " | awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i }' | grep '2.3.'`. It lists all the versions of rails 2.3, and the one at the top is the latest one.

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I think of that?  (But seriously, I think the -a option on the gem list is what I was missing.  This answer is closest to what I was looking for, so I'm accepting it. Thanks.)

Answer (score 3):

http://rubygems.org/gems/rails lists the most recently-released versions. 2.3.11 is the most recent version of Rails 2.3.

Comment: This is a page that should be linked to from the rails web site.  This is a good answer.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

http://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions shows all 2.3 gem releases, although the [github 2.3 stable branch](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/2-3-stable) shows a few commits after this which haven't been released as a gem.